# How to check on hosted webpage when my nodeMCU goes offline?

Tags: php, iot, pubnub, nodemcu

I have nodeMCU sending data to database. It is visible in a webpage coded with PHP, hosted online. I need some functionality to give presence of the device. How can I make it possible for nodeMCU to show it's presence? 
I got to know about PubNub and it's services, but it seems to work only for webpages, not for hardware devices pinging back to webpage.

Please consider, I am a noob into this. Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: You can use PHP curl to get the page where its visible.

Comment: What are you trying to do? What is the use case? What have you already done? How many devices are you working with?